# Read a particular word from a file in C++ quickly

Tags: c++, performance

My Manager has told me to create a test for which I am required to test whether a particular word exists in a File or not. The problem is that the File maybe very big & if the test runs for a long time then it will be failed during regression testing. So I want to know if there is any convenience API in standard C++ for my purpose which would quickly tell me whether the word exists or not. I dont want to know the location of the word. The word is somewhere near the beginning of the File but its exact location is not known.
Any help in this regard?
Thank You.

Comment: What is a large file for you?

Comment: Will you be looking for a different word each time? Can you preprocess the file? You might want to look into [bloom filters](http://www.jasondavies.com/bloomfilter/) - it'll tell very quickly (constant time) if the word is *not* there.

Comment: @TonyTheLion around 100MB, but since the regression testing is done on older machines with poor resources, hence the concern...

Comment: @sftrabbit there is only a particular word each time. & bloom filters looks like a 3rd party app, a strict no-no here, apart from the fact that it is not C++.

Comment: Bloom filters are an algorithm. If you don't like the existing implementations, write your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file has no particular structure, other than to contain words (in any order), the only solution is linear search, which means reading the entire file.  If you know that the word can only be near the beginning, then you only have to search to the furthest point the word can be found.

If that's not fast enough, you either have to structure the file somehow (sorted, etc.), or you have to speed up the reading proceudre itself (e.g. use `mmap`).

Comment: thank you for the answer!
Can you please recommend a function in C++ which I should use for reading & comparing the fastest?
I havent used standard C++ much, used a lot to Qt C++.

Comment: @CAD_coding What have you got so far?  And what does the file actually look like?

Comment: I have followed your advise & I am reading from the beginning, I am successfull in reading the file but I am having a problem which I cannot understand. I will post a different question & give you the link. Thank You for your concern.

Comment: I have posted the question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338147/crash-while-reading-a-file-in-c

Answer (score 0):

`mmap` the file and then `strnstr` it would probably be the best. Unless you know something clever about the structure of the file that would restrict the area you have to search in.

```
extern "C" {
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
}

#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // I don't check the arguments here, you should probably do that

    // String to search for
    char* search_string = argv[2];

    // Open the file so we can map it
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        std::cout << "Open failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Find the length of the file so we know how much to map
    off_t len = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (len == -1) {
        std::cout << "Seek failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // map the file into memory
    char* file_contents = (char*)mmap(
        NULL, len, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE | MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (file_contents == MAP_FAILED) {
        std::cout << "map failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // We don't need the file open any more, we do need to unmap it later though
    close(fd);

    // Search for the string in the file here
    char* found = strnstr(file_contents, search_string, len);
    if (found == NULL)
        std::cout << "String not found" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "String found @ " << found - file_contents << std::endl;

    munmap(file_contents, len);
}
```

Comment: I havent heard of this memmap anywhere, is it a function in C++?

Comment: I mis-spelt `mmap`. It is a unix function for mapping a file into memory rather than reading it through the `read`/`write` interface.

Comment: First, of course, neither `strnstr` nor `mmap` are standard C++.  `mmap` _is_ standard Unix, and there is similar functionality in Windows.  `strnstr` isn't even standard Unix; it _looks_ like a BSD extention, and from the documentation I've been able to find, it doesn't look like it will do what he wants.

Comment: No, almost none of it is standard C++. This tends to be the trade-off that is made when searching for speed though. `strnstr` should work on recent versions of linux, mac & BSD. In it's absence you could-null-terminate manually. There are equivalent functions for most OSes I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Memory Mapped file access allows you to access parts of the file directly without loading it into memory.

Qt provides memory mapping as far as I know, boost, too, the C++ standard library doesn't.

You could also use the native API of the OS. `mmap` for UNIX, `CreateFileMapping` for Windows.