# Crash while reading a File in C++

Tags: c++

I want to search a particular word in a file & return a result as to whether that word exists in the file or not. I have created a function which does this. But while returning the program is crashing. Here is the code:

```
bool FindMyWord(const char *fileName)
{
    ifstream myFile (fileName);
    if(!myFile)
        return false;

    string wordSearch = "MyWord";
    string endSearch = "LastWord";
    bool result;
    while(1)
    {
        char read[20];
        myFile.getline(read, 1000, '\n');
        string line(read, read+20);
        if(line.find(wordSearch) != string::npos)
        {
            result = true;
            break; //comes here after looping about 10 times
        }
        if(line.find(endSearch) != string::npos)
        {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    myFile.close();
    return result;
} // <- crash when F10 is pressed after this
```

In VS2010 while debugging I find that the crash is happening after executing "`return result;`" in second last line of the function i.e. when the yellow cursor is for the last closing bracket of function.
I am getting a message

```
A buffer overrun has occurred in myApp.exe which has corrupted the program's internal
state. Press Break to debug the program or Continue to terminate the program.
```

What is this error? I am calling the function like this :

```
bool result = FindMyWord("myFileName.stp");
```

**UPDATE**: Each line has varying no of characters & they are > 20. I want to read the 1st 20 characters & if the word does not exist in those characters then I want to jump to the next line. Initially I had used `myFile.getline(read, 20, '\n');` But after the 1st loop every subsequent looping resulted in NULL being passed to read. So I made it to read 1000 because before reading 1000 chars it would find '\n' & go to next line.
A better mechanism of achieving the same would be very helpful.

Comment: Your call to `myFile.getline` is attempting to read up to 1000 characters into a buffer that can only store 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a `std::string` instead of a fixed length buffer?

```
bool FindMyWord(const char *fileName)
{
    std::ifstream myFile (fileName);
    if(!myFile) {
        return false;
    }

    std::string wordSearch = "MyWord";
    std::string endSearch = "LastWord";
    bool result;
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(myFile, line))
    {
        if(line.find(wordSearch) != std::string::npos)
        {
            result = true;
            break; //comes here after looping about 10 times
        }
        if(line.find(endSearch) != std::string::npos)
        {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    myFile.close();
    return result;
}
```

Buffer overflows have been responsible for far too many security problems. Just don't use fixed length buffers!

This is also slightly more correct, as it checks for errors on the stream.

PS I hate `using namespace std`!

Comment: @MM. In all fairness, I copied and pasted the OP's code and added `std::` as appropriate. I missed one by the looks of it. On the other hand, it obliterates your symbol table and it confuses everyone a lot if you define your own `std` like methods in your own namespace with the same names.

Answer (score 3):

`myFile.getline(read, 1000, '\n');` will read up to 1000 bytes into memory starting at address `read`.  `read` is a 20 byte stack buffer so you risk writing beyond the end of your allocated memory.  The effects of doing this are undefined but a crash is very likely.

To fix this, you should pass the size of the `read` buffer into `getline`;

```
myFile.getline(read, sizeof(read), '\n');
```

(Note that `sizeof(read)` only works for a stack buffer.  If `read` was allocated on the heap, `sizeof` would only tell you the size of the pointer rather than the allocated memory it points to.)

Comment: yes I had tried that but the problem is that once the first loop is over every subsequent looping reulted in NULL being passed into read by getline.
I want to read line by line & check if the word is present in the begining of the line & if it is not present then it should jump to second line.

Comment: Is that because your test file has lines longer than 19 chars?  Your algorithm relies on `read` being big enough to fit all of the largest possible test line.  The easiest 'fix' here would be to increase the size of the `read` array.

Comment: OK, but is not possible to read only the first 20 chars then jump to next line if the word is not found?

Comment: @CAD_coding You can't really jump around a file like that. You can seek to a specific byte position, but not *the next line*.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain if I change the call to
    myFile.getline(read, 20);
or
    myFile.getline(read, 20, '\n');
it is reading NULL after 1st loop, then what should I do?

Comment: If you absolutely want to read into a 20 byte buffer, use [istream.read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) and add your own checking for line endings.  If this seems like too much work and you want to stick with `getline`, you need to read into a buffer that is big enough for the longest line.  You can always ignore words that are longer than 20 bytes or run beyond the first 20 bytes.

Comment: @simonc Thank You, I find Alex's solution easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Until you can get the code working, forget about `char[]`.  (As
others have pointed out, you have a buffer overrun.  Very easy
to do with any C style array as a local variable.)  Since you're
looking for words, the initial code can be something as simple
as:

```
std::string word;
while ( myFile >> word && word != "MyWord" && word != "LastWord" ) {
}
return word == "MyWord";
```

This can certainly be made faster, but if `"LastWord"` isn't
very far into the file, it might not be necessary.  (BYW: it's
generally not necessary to close a file used in input.  The
destructor will take care of that, and since you've checked the
status after each input anyway, there's no more error checking
to worry about.)

Comment: I have updated the Question. Hope you understand my requirement.
Does your code's reading occur line by line or char by char?

Comment: The fact that the word must be in the first 20 characters of the line changes things considerably.  The first solution which comes to mind would be to read lines, then break the first 20 characters of each line up into words and searching those.  (Note that the solutions proposed elsewhere, using `std::string::find` do _not_ look for words, but for substrings.)

Answer (score 0):

One place I can think of in above code causing buffer over run is:

myFile.getline(read, 1000, '\n');

Since 'read' is a buffer having space for 20 characters, it can not accomodate if file got a line bigger than that.

Also, please do eof check. I would suggest something like this:

```
bool FindMyWord(const char *fileName)
{
    if(!myFile)
        return false;
```

```
ifstream myFile (fileName);

const char* wordSearch = "MyWord";
const char* endSearch  = "LastWord";
bool result = false;
string line;

while(std::getline(myFile, line))
{
    if(line.find(wordSearch, 0, 20) != string::npos)
    {
        result = true;
        break; //comes here after looping about 10 times
    }

    if(line.find(endSearch, 0, 20) != string::npos)
    {
        result = false;
        break;
    }
}

myFile.close();
return result;
```

}

Comment: Thank You for the answer I understood my mistake & I have implemented Alex's solution.

Comment: I believe, you want to check first 20 characters only, then you need to change 'find' as per my updated code. Also, check for null filename before you pass that to ifstream constructor.

Comment: And how are you going to differentiate between these two cases a. file does not have word 'LastWord' and b. file has that word ? Both will return 'false'.

Comment: That does not matter as that check is just to finish reading the file quickly, as I know that the word I am searching for does not exist below the line of endSearch!